# Google Maps API OverlayView() not working in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

There is now problem with namespace in my directive "map" because the mapInit() function is done well. But i get an error with my OverlayView() object and cant fix it. This is just the first step of the google documentation for "Custom Overlays" but it doesn't work.

Error: "ReferenceError: MapSymbol is not defined"

```
app.directive('map', function() {


var linkFunction = function(scope, element, attrs) {

    MapSymbol.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    var map;
    function initMap () {
        map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 3
    });
    }

    initMap();
};


return {
    link: linkFunction,
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/map.html'
};});
```

Comment: Where are you defining `MapSymbol`?

Comment: When i look in the reference example there is nothing more? should i defining it? and how? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want to play with google maps. You can use this http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/ for easier loading of maps in angular. It has most of features enabled which are present in maps.

Comment: That helps me a lot. Thank you!